# Spring Boot and CORS

Tags: spring-boot, cors

I facing issue with CORS in spring boot. I have configured CORS like this

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

which I suppose enables all header and other stuff.

It works excellently with GET request

```js
 $.get("someUrl, function(data, status){
     console.log(data[0].latitude);
 });
```

But whenever I make POST request like this

```js
 $.ajax({
        url: 'someUrl',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        data: object
    });
```

I get the following

```
OPTIONS XHR  "someUrl" [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 4ms]
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at  "someUrl". 
(Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Whatever it is that causes the problem, I don't think it is within the snippets you have posted in the question. I just tried it on a fresh Spring Boot (1.3.2.) setup with a minimum amount of code and the CORS headers are correctly added when I `POST` from other domains. What version of Boot are you using and from what user agent do you `POST` your requests? May other dependencies in your project override your Cors settings (or maybe more explicit configuration on the controllers?)?

Comment: I use Spring Boot 1.3.0.RELEASE and user agent is Firefox. Actually it is Api-gateway application which redirects to other endpoints of other spring boot applications. I use Zuul from netflix.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Simple way of configuring CORS filter with Spring Boot app is to make `@Component` class which implements `Filter` like this:

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Location");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}

}
```

It works great with *`spring-boot 1.3.0`*

***EDIT (October 2017):***

Still works with *`spring-boot 1.5.8`*

Comment: If you are using http basic authentication, don't forget to add the token `Authorization` in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

Comment: The `Filter` being implemented here is `javax.servlet.Filter`

Answer (score -1):

You not specified all attributes which required for correctly processing. Minimum variant:

```property
path="/**"
allowed-origins="*"
allowed-methods="GET"
allowed-origin-patterns=".*"
```

---

Usually `path="/**"`, `allowed-origins="*"` etc. **not safety variant**. I understand that making a lot of code class with different configuration - not extendable variant for long pipeline

---

I can proposition using my implementation for this or you can fork this code
add dependency

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.iruzhnikov</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc-cors-properties-autoconfigure</artifactId>
  <version>VERSION</version>
</dependency>
```

and add configuration

```yml
spring:
  web:
    cors:
      enabled: true
      mappings:
        baseOrigins:
          paths: /**
          allowed-origins: "http://localhost:4200"
          allowed-origin-patterns: .*
```