# How to configure CORS in a Spring Boot + Spring Security application?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, cors

I use Spring Boot with Spring Security and Cors Support.

If I execute following code

```
url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/token'
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = ->
    if xmlhttp.readyState is 4
        console.log xmlhttp.status
xmlhttp.open "GET", url, true
# xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader 'Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa 'a:a'
do xmlhttp.send
```

I get as a result

```
200
```

If I test with wrong credentials like

```
url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/token'
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = ->
    if xmlhttp.readyState is 4
        console.log xmlhttp.status
xmlhttp.open "GET", url, true
# xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader 'Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa 'a:aa'
do xmlhttp.send
```

instead of getting 401 (that is the standard code for wrong authentication in spring security) I get

```
0
```

with following browser notification:

GET http://localhost:5000/api/token

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5000. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

I'm developing front-end code that needs useful http status codes from server responses to handle the situation. I need something more useful than 0. Also the response body is empty. I dont know if my config is wrong, or it's a software bug and I also don't know where, if it's chromium (using arch linux) or spring security.

My Spring Config is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
public class Controller {
    @RequestMapping("token")
    @CrossOrigin
    Map<String, String> token(HttpSession session) {
        return Collections.singletonMap("token", session.getId());
    }
}

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("a").password("a").roles("USER");
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(CorsUtils::isPreFlightRequest).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();
    }
}
```

If I test with curl everything works perfect, I think because no CORS support needed, but I tried to simulate the CORS with OPTION requests and the result was also ok.

```
$ curl -v localhost:5000/api/token -H "Authorization: Basic YTpha"
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET /api/token HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.48.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Basic YTpha
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS,DELETE
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,Accept,X-Requested-    With,Content-Type,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization
< x-auth-token: 58e4cca9-7719-46c8-9180-2fc16aec8dff
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Sun, 01 May 2016 16:15:44 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"token":"58e4cca9-7719-46c8-9180-2fc16aec8dff"}
```

and with wrong credentials:

```
$ curl -v localhost:5000/api/token -H "Authorization: Basic YTp"
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET /api/token HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.48.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Basic YTp
> 
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Sun, 01 May 2016 16:16:15 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"timestamp":1462119375041,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Failed to decode basic authentication token","path":"/api/token"}
```

Edit:
To avoid misunderstandings. I use 1.3.3 Spring Boot.
The Blog post writes:

> CORS support will be available in the upcoming Spring Boot 1.3 release, and is already available in the 1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT builds.
>
> Using controller method CORS configuration with @CrossOrigin annotations in your Spring Boot application does not require any specific configuration.
>
> Global CORS configuration can be defined by registering a WebMvcConfigurer bean with a customized addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry) method:

I have added following code to enable global cors support. actually I have tried this before but it the result was the same. I tried it again recently and the result is the same.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The idea, that the problem comes from a redirect between the authorization process is an interesting though. how can i change the redirect to any resources to avoid this conflict?

EDIT:

I guess I am closer to a solution. I have tested with my nodejs server that supports cors without problems by adding 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
to all requests.

Like Stefan Isele has already mentioned it seems that spring security redirects or doesn't add the CORS header so that's why the request seems to be broken. So while spring security is checking the authentification it has to add the proper header.

Does anyone know how to do so?

EDIT:

I found a workaround, that seems to be ugly. I have started a github issue for spring boot where I describe the workaround: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5834

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35040051/2884309 <- this solution still works on spring-boot 1.5.6

Comment: does it also works for the PUT request or we have to define that separately. 
By default all origins and GET, HEAD and POST methods are allowed. From Spring Documentation ^^

Comment: This is not to be used if your application is just a rest api application with spring security. Configuring CORS in a spring security application is done using a `CorsConfigurationSource ` pointed out in an answer further down.

Answer (score 107):

Spring Security can now leverage Spring MVC CORS support described in [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework) I wrote.

To make it work, you need to explicitly enable CORS support at Spring Security level as following, otherwise CORS enabled requests may be blocked by Spring Security before reaching Spring MVC.

If you are using controller level `@CrossOrigin` annotations, you just have to enable Spring Security CORS support and it will leverage Spring MVC configuration:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()...
    }
}
```

If you prefer using CORS global configuration, you can declare a `CorsConfigurationSource` bean as following:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()...
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }
}
```

This approach supersedes the [filter-based approach](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework#filter-based-cors-support) previously recommended.

You can find more details in the [dedicated CORS section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#cors) of Spring Security documentation.

Comment: I made CORS+Spring Security work using a `CorsFilter` bean. For some reason, the FilterRegistrationBean wasn't picked up.

Comment: hi, i have this:
 <mvc:cors>
  <mvc:mapping path="/rest/client/**" allowed-headers="*" allowed-methods="GET,PUT,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,DELETE,PATCH" allowed-origins="*" allow-credentials="true" />
 </mvc:cors>
in my dispatcher-servlet. and this:   <cors /> in my security.xml. But when i turn on authentication it is not working. There is no logging. Any clues?

Comment: Adding that if you use a @RepositoryRestResource,
You have to enable it specifically, another way:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724994/spring-data-rest-and-cors#answer-42403956

Comment: Hi, I'm trying the second way, but then Springs decodes every JWT Token to "anonymousUser".

Comment: It should replace the `HttpSecurity` configuration specific to your application.

Comment: `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` was deprecated in Spring Security 5.7.0-M2 https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

Answer (score 87):

If you use JDK 8+, there is a one line lambda solution:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
}
```

Comment: What does it do exactly? The javascript client request will not complain anymore about "blocked by CORS policy"?

Comment: `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` was deprecated in Spring Security 5.7.0-M2 https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

Answer (score 74):

## How to Solve CORS on Spring Boot 2.7+

#### Summary

If you are facing this CORS issue, don't worry. It's a common issue for every backend developer when they try to integrate with front-end microservices for the first-time. It's some sort of security policy that browsers are strictly applying for the safety of the users and that's why you are not facing it when you tried your API via Postman/Swagger or cURL.

### Solutions

- #### Client-Side Bypass (Dev Only)

Following solutions are just only for development purposes, you absolutely need to solve this CORS issue permanently for your production environment. You can use the following browser extensions to bypass browser policies for CORS error but don't get surprised if they didn't work properly.

1. CORS Unblock [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-unblock/) - [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-unblock/lfhmikememgdcahcdlaciloancbhjino?hl=en)
2. CORS Everywhere [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/access-control-allow-origin/)

- #### Production Solutions

There are different ways to configure CORS policies on the application and it's completely based on your deployment architecture. For example, if your application is going to be exposed through Reverse Proxies (like Nginx), API Gateways (Kong), Service Mesh Sidecar Proxies (i.e Envoy), Kubernetes NGINX Ingress, and so forth, **the Best Practice is to handle the CORS configuration on the Edge layer** because sometimes they don't consider lower layers headers and they overwrite them and you will still receive CORS errors from the Browser.
I have listed useful links for the configuration of edge layers in the following

- Kubernetes NGINX Ingress Controller CORS - [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57301211/how-to-enable-cors-with-ingress-without-using-nginx) / [Official User Manual](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/)
- Kong API Gateway - [KongHQ](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/cors/)
- Nginx - [Geekflare](https://geekflare.com/enable-cors-apache-nginx/)
- Apache - [Geekflare](https://geekflare.com/enable-cors-apache-nginx/)
- HA Proxy - [Official Website](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/enabling-cors-in-haproxy/)
- Istio - [Discuss.Istio](https://discuss.istio.io/t/configuring-cors/7458/4)

But, If you are going to deploy and expose your APIs through SprintBoot's built-in web server, you can use the instructions in the next.

#### Instructions to Enable CORS Globally - Spring Boot Application

If you don't have any implementation for WebSecurityConfig, Just easily do the following steps:

1. Add the following dependency [**spring-boot-starter-security**]
   to your pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2. Create a new class in your config package that extends
   WebSecurityConfig (i.e 'SecurityConfig')
3. Put the following codes into the created file:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.CorsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.servlet.HttpSecurityDsl;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;

import java.util.List;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PUT","OPTIONS","PATCH", "DELETE"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));

        return http
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests
                                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .csrf(HttpSecurityDsl::disable)
                .build();
    }
}
```

4. Now you need to customize the CORS configuration based on your need:

   - **setAllowedHeaders**-> you have to specify which parameters are allowed to be sent to the backend services through the front-end app, for example, if you are using Bearer/Basic Token Authorization methods, you need to pass your JWT-Token through the "Authorization" header. So you need to make sure that backed would accept this data accordingly and for this purpose, you must put "Authorization" in the list of Allowed-Headers.
   - **setAllowedMethods**-> Do not forget to put "OPTIONS" method in the list for Pre-flight process. Don't worry, [read more here!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)
   - **setAllowCredentials**-> If you are using Authorization header, set it True.
   - **setExposedHeaders**-> If you are returning data through Response Headers, you need to specify them here. for example, some APIs are designed to return Authorization token after success /authentication through Response Headers. Thus, the related header needs to be exposed accordingly.
   - **setAllowedOrigins**-> You must specify the domains that are eligible to send requests to your backend applications. for example, if your application is hosted on https://penguin.com and your APIs are on https://api.penguin.com, you need to allow "https://penguing.com" to send requests to your backend. Also, you are able to pass wildcard (*) to allow any domains to send requests to your backend. But it's recommended to not use "any" unless you are providing public APIs or you are deploying in the non-production environments.

   *There is an important misunderstanding for the people that may think CORS can avoid misuses of the APIs by/on other platforms (i.e phishing purposes). **It's not true**, CORS Policies are browser-based policies and can be bypassed easily through proxies, so it only makes the misuse process a little bit harder, but it does not make immunity.*
5. Build/Run your application, Test your APIs, and rest ( Everyone knows CORS headache )

#### Alternative Solutions

You can use the following links:

[Spring.io | Enabling Cross-Origin Requests for a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)

[Bealdung | CORS with Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors)

Comment: This saved me a couple of hours, thanks!
A small change that worked for me completely, change this line
corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins to
corsConfiguration.setAllowedOriginPatterns

Comment: @Soroosh Khodami is there a way strict on the same domain but for the ports,
Ex: www.corscheck.com:8081
     www.corscheck.com:8056 Ports could change but the domain will remain the same so how can I restrict only to check the domain (domains are not known before hand and they could change according to the client)

Comment: @Shamitha Silva I think there is no sign of source port in the HTTP Request Headers. So it should be managed in the Firewall.

Comment: E.g. using Springboot 2.7.4 the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated.

Answer (score 46):

If you are using **Spring Security**, you can do the following to ensure that CORS requests are handled first:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            // by default uses a Bean by the name of corsConfigurationSource
            .cors().and()
            ...
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://example.com"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

See [Spring 4.2.x CORS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/cors.html) for more information.

**Without** Spring Security this will work:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("*")
                    .allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I copied the codes solution called "Without Spring Security" in My MainApplicationFile but it didn't work :(

Comment: None of these worked for me. I keep getting 401 with Option Requests.

Comment: Works perfectly! It is important to remember that (as you said) if you are using Spring Security, you should use the first code snippet to ensure that CORS requests are handled first... That was the key in my case. Thank you so much!

Comment: there is a syntax error for "...". what's the reason for that?

Answer (score 12):

```java
// CorsConfig.java file
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }
}
```

As of 2021, this is maybe the simplest solution, just need to create a separate class.

That's all.

Answer (score 11):

Cross origin protection is a feature of the browser. Curl does not care for CORS, as you presumed. 
That explains why your curls are successful, while the browser requests are not.

If you send the browser request with the wrong credentials, spring will try to forward the client to a login page.
This response (off the login page) does not contain the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' and the browser reacts as you describe.

You must make spring to include the haeder for this login response, and may be for other response, like error pages etc.

This can be done like this :

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://domain2.com")
                    .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE")
                    .allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3")
                    .exposedHeaders("header1", "header2")
                    .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);
            }
     }
```

This is copied from [cors-support-in-spring-framework](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework)

I would start by adding cors mapping for all resources with :

```
registry.addMapping("/**")
```

and also allowing all methods headers..
Once it works you may start to reduce that again to the needed minimum.

Please note, that the CORS configuration changes with Release 4.2.

If this does not solve your issues, post the response you get from the failed ajax request.

Answer (score 6):

Found an easy solution for Spring-Boot, Spring-Security and Java-based config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors().configurationSource(new CorsConfigurationSource() {
            @Override
            public CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request) {
                return new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `@Configuration`, if you are using `@EnableWebSecurity`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem on a methood that returns the status of the server.
The application is deployed on multiple servers. So the easiest I found is to add

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping(value="/schedulerActive")
public String isSchedulerActive(){
  //code goes here
}
```

This method is not secure but you can add `allowCredentials` for that.

Answer (score 6):

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("*");
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Don't just add the answer, try explaining your answer.

Comment: WebMvsConfigure is a bean created the. addMapping("*") means any endpoint and addOrigins("*") means any body can access and allowedMathods("*") any type of request can be served

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by:

```java
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

    @Configuration
    public class CORSFilter extends CorsFilter {

        public CORSFilter(CorsConfigurationSource source) {
            super((CorsConfigurationSource) source);
        }

        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
            if (response.getHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin") == null)
                response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }
```

and:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

    @Configuration
    public class RestConfig {

        @Bean
        public CORSFilter corsFilter() {
            CorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
            config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");
            config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.DELETE);
            config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
            config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.OPTIONS);
            config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.PUT);
            config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
            ((UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource) source).registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
            return new CORSFilter(source);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by:
`

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers","Origin","Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "Authorization"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("DELETE", "GET", "POST", "PATCH", "PUT"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

`

Answer (score 3):

```java
// https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.2/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-cors
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(final CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*").allowedHeaders("*");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If using Spring Security, set additional:

```java
// https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.2/reference/html5/#cors
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // ...

        // if Spring MVC is on classpath and no CorsConfigurationSource is provided,
        // Spring Security will use CORS configuration provided to Spring MVC
        http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults());
    }
}
```

Comment: Though it works for Spring 2.7.4 the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated (nowadays).

Answer (score 2):

Cors can be a pain in the ass, but with this simple code you are Cors ONLY!!!! to to specified method

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="*")// in this line add your url and thats is all for spring boot side
    @GetMapping("/some")
    public String index() {
        return "pawned cors!!!!";
    }
```

Like a charm in spring boot 2.0.2

Answer (score 2):

I was having major problems with Axios, Spring Boot and Spring Security with authentication.

Please note the version of Spring Boot and the Spring Security you are using matters.

Spring Boot: 1.5.10
Spring: 4.3.14
Spring Security 4.2.4

To resolve this issue using Annotation Based Java Configuration I created the following class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("youruser").password("yourpassword")
                .authorities("ROLE_USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors().and().
                authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(CorsUtils:: isPreFlightRequest).permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .realmName("Biometrix");

        http.csrf().disable();

    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

One of the major gotchas with Axios is that when your API requires authentication it sends an Authorization header with the OPTIONS request.  If you do not include Authorization in the allowed headers configuration setting our OPTIONS request (aka PreFlight request) will fail and Axios will report an error.

As you can see with a couple of simple and properly placed settings CORS configuration with SpringBoot is pretty easy.

Comment: At Spring 1.5.3 there is no permitAll() on the requestMatcher(CorsUtils::isPreFlightRequest)....grrrrr

Answer (score 2):

After much searching for the error coming from javascript CORS, the only elegant solution I found for this case was configuring the cors of Spring's own class org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration.CorsConfiguration()

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can finish this with only a **Single Class**, Just add this on your class path.

This **one is enough** for **Spring Boot**, **Spring Security**, nothing else. 
:

```
        @Component
        @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
        public class MyCorsFilterConfig implements Filter {

            @Override
            public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
                final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Type, enctype");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
                if (HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name().equalsIgnoreCase(((HttpServletRequest) req).getMethod())) {
                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                } else {
                    chain.doFilter(req, res);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void destroy() {
            }

            @Override
            public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

For properties configuration

```
# ENDPOINTS CORS CONFIGURATION (EndpointCorsProperties)
endpoints.cors.allow-credentials= # Set whether credentials are supported. When not set, credentials are not supported.
endpoints.cors.allowed-headers= # Comma-separated list of headers to allow in a request. '*' allows all headers.
endpoints.cors.allowed-methods=GET # Comma-separated list of methods to allow. '*' allows all methods.
endpoints.cors.allowed-origins= # Comma-separated list of origins to allow. '*' allows all origins. When not set, CORS support is disabled.
endpoints.cors.exposed-headers= # Comma-separated list of headers to include in a response.
endpoints.cors.max-age=1800 # How long, in seconds, the response from a pre-flight request can be cached by clients.
```

Comment: These properties are for Spring Actuator only and don't apply to all endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin solution

```
...
http.cors().configurationSource {
  CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues()
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Webflux (Reactive) Spring Boot, since Google shows this as one of the top results when searching with 'Reactive' for this same problem. Using Spring boot version 2.2.2

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
  return http.cors().and().build();
}

@Bean
public CorsWebFilter corsFilter() {
  CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();

  config.applyPermitDefaultValues();

  config.addAllowedHeader("Authorization");

  UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
  source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

  return new CorsWebFilter(source);
}
```

For a full example, with the setup that works with a custom authentication manager (in my case JWT authentication). See here https://gist.github.com/FiredLight/d973968cbd837048987ab2385ba6b38f

Answer (score 1):

Note that `new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues()` only allows GET, POST and HEAD methods. If you are looking for PUT or DELETE, you have to set the methods manually (like below). Finally, don't forget the OPTIONS method which is required to preflight PUT, PATCH and DELETE methods (CORS error will still occur otherwise).

```
import static org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration.ALL;

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(
            HttpMethod.GET.name(),
            HttpMethod.POST.name(),
            HttpMethod.DELETE.name(),
            HttpMethod.PUT.name(),
            HttpMethod.HEAD.name(),
            HttpMethod.POST.name(),
            HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name()
    ));
    config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList(ALL));
    config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList(ALL));
    config.setMaxAge(1800L);
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return source;
}
```

Comment: i like this approach, it fits best with the Spring Security 27.6 upward.
I have one problem with this instead of Filter based approach. How can we add the Cache related headers like `Cache-Control` , how we can add a high cache value for the pre-flight requests while keep it low for actual requests?

Answer (score 1):

In class implement WebMvcConfigurer you have to Override method addCorsMappings

```
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final long MAX_AGE_SECS;


    @Value("${appConfig.cors.allowedOrigins}")
    private String[] allowedOrigins;

    public WebMvcConfig() {
        MAX_AGE_SECS = 3600;
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedOrigins(allowedOrigins)
        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
        .allowedHeaders("*")
        .allowCredentials(true)
        .maxAge(MAX_AGE_SECS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Spring Security 6.1.0`, you can configure it as follows.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            // by default uses a Bean by the name of corsConfigurationSource
            .cors(withDefaults())
            ...
        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*")); 
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

[Spring Security:Spring's CORS Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/cors.html#page-title)

Comment: where the `withDefaults()` came from ?

Answer (score 0):

Newer Spring boot methods you can look into this:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedMethods("*")
                    .allowedHeaders("*")
                    .allowedOrigins("*");
        }
    };
}
```