# How to configure CORS and Basic Authorization in Spring Boot?

Tags: ajax, security, spring-boot, cors, basic-authentication

I'm trying to configure CORS in a Spring boot application that already has Basic auth set up.

I've searched in many places, including [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37610988/1121497), that points to [Filter based CORS support](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework#filter-based-cors-support) in the official docs.

So far no luck.

My AJAX request is done this way. It works if done from same origin http://localhost:8080.

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/lists', {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic dXNlckB0ZXN0LmNvbToxMjM0NQ=='
  }
}
```

The AJAX request is done from a React app at http://localhost:3000, so I tried the following Spring boot CORS config:

```
@Configuration
class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter()
    {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000"));
        // Maybe I can just say "*" for methods and headers
        // I just copied these lists from another Dropwizard project
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "HEAD"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("X-Requested-With", "Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept",
            "Authorization", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Access-Control-Max-Age",
            "Access-Control-Request-Headers", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Age", "Allow", "Alternates",
            "Content-Range", "Content-Disposition", "Content-Description"));
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);

        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

My WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.httpBasic().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/index.html").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
    }
}
```

The `fetch` call from http://localhost:3000 displays this 401 error in the console:

> Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:8080/api/lists. Response for
>   preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401.

[image]

An in the network tab of chrome dev tools I see this OPTIONS request:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you need to allow `OPTION` requests into your web security config. Something like:

`.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/your-url").permitAll()`

Comment: Thanks! You were right! For now, just to see it works, I used `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()`. It works with my `FilterRegistrationBean`. Maybe it also works with the `CorsFilter`, but the problem was the OPTIONS call was being blocked.

Answer (score 5):

The browser checks CORS settings via a request with OPTIONS header. And if you've configured authorization, OPTIONS request will be blocked as unauthorized.

You can simply allow OPTIONS request via cors support in WebConfigurerAdapter.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // ...
        http.cors();
    }
}
```

Check this link for more info: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-cors-preflight

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

  @Bean
  public CorsFilter corsFilter() {

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(false); //updated to false
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
  }

  @Bean
  public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
      }
    };
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you but same result... I've also added my config setting to your solution but nothing changes. I'm not using Spring MVC, but I included your `WebMvcConfigurer` too just in case.

Comment: Are you using Boot with Angular 2

Comment: Why do you ask? I'm using React right now, to try it, but I'm planning to try Angular 2 too. Anyway, I'm calling the `@RestController` using the `fetch` function. I mean that no React components are involved in the call.