# How to fix Spring Security Authorization header not being passed?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

In one of my REST services, I make use of Spring Security to validate the token that is being passed in the header. However, spring is unable to find the "Authorization" header, even though it is there. This was not a problem when testing in test, and even locally but when we deployed to PROD we get this issue.

As an alternative/workaround I removed Spring security and instead tried to do the validation of my token in the actual endpoint before continueing with the rest of the request like such:

```
@PostMapping(value="/create",consumes="application/json; charset=utf-8")
    @CrossOrigin
    public ResponseEntity createAccount(@RequestBody MerchantAccount merchantAccount,@RequestHeader(name="Authorization") String token) {
        log.info("Checking User Token");
        if(!jwtUtil.isAuthorizedToken(token))
            return ResponseEntity.status(401).build();
//some creating Account Logic
}
```

If I did the above once again it would work in TEST and on LOCAL but not in PROD. Error that I would get back would be "Missing Authorization header". But yet again it is present. (Tested from postman to).

After some research, I saw that I could add ",required=false" so spring would not check for it, but then still there was no token to extract.

The only difference between PROD and TEST and my local is the following:

Java version
java version on test:`java version "1.6.0_32"`

java version on PROD: `java version "1.8.0_121"`

java version on local:`java version "1.8.0_221"`

On Test we use HTTP and PROD it's HTTPS.
Spring Security Version in POM file is 5.2

**EDIT**
In my web config I do have a section that allows for the "Authorization" header to be present as seen below.

```
 @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(ImmutableList.of("*"));//YOLO Allow all origins, we can change this once we go to prod
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(ImmutableList.of("HEAD",
                "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH","OPTIONS"));//Allowed Methods
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(ImmutableList.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type","Access-Control-Request-Headers","Access-Control-Request-Method",
               "Accept","Access-Control-Allow-Headers"));//Allowed Headers
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

**Update**
On TEST & LOCAL when I iterate through headers in the request filter (as seen below)

```
@Component
@Service
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.info("Done Getting Headers");
        Collections.list(request.getHeaderNames()).forEach(item -> logger.info("header name is " + item));
        logger.info("Done Getting Headers");
        boolean isAccessToken = true;
        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("authorization");//This is null as the Authorization header is not found in request
}
```

I get the following output.
TEST & LOCAL

[image: Working Test]

On PROD I get the following:

[image: prod result]

Please help.

Comment: Does the header have an actual value? Could be empty. If you are running behind a proxy/firewall/load-balancer/.. . it could be that the header is already blocked there and it isn't accesible anymore for downstream services (at least that is what this looks like). I would suggest take a look at the bigger picture (include infrastructure) and map the differences. I suspect you will find that something is blocking/filtering it there. And remove the workaround, if Spring Security cannot get it with a `request.getHeader` neither can you.

Comment: Did you check your nginx / proxy config file for something that might filter out the header?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After wandering galaxies....

I've fixed it using this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Config extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and() /*.other stuff */;
    }
}
```

Basically **you need to enable `cors()` with the `http` object..**
and then there are multiple ways to handle the cros origin for each controller/method or globally.

My issue was like this:

Whenever I make request from postman it worked & the `"Authorization"` key in header was always present, debugged it using request filter just like you.

However, each time request made form front end app (react) the browser prevented  the`"Authorization"` key every single time...

To configure it globally:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry
                  .addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig")
                  .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080");
        }
    };
}
```

Or, controller level,

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
@GetMapping("/greeting")
public String greeting() {
    return "works!";
}
```

Ref:

[SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60933851/7267150),
[Spring Official Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)

Comment: Did you solve this? Authorization header while making request from React?

Comment: @UjjwalMishra yes, my issue was fixed, I was making request from react

Answer (score 1):

When using **Spring Security** with **Spring web flux**, I had to use the following config to make it work: -

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.SecurityWebFiltersOrder;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

    http.cors().and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        .anyExchange()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        ... //more mappings 

    return http.build();
  }

  @Bean
  CorsConfigurationSource corsConfiguration() {
    CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfig.applyPermitDefaultValues();
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source =
        new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig);
    return source;
  }

}
```