# axios 403 forbidden on OPTIONS request

Tags: java, reactjs, redux, axios, create-react-app

I am working on an application using React+Redux and using `axios` to make api calls.

Here's a sample call which fails:

```
axios.post(`${API_ROOT}${FIND_USER}${currentUserID}`, {
        headers: {
                'Authorization': token
        },
      })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("Sucess")
    })
```

Request url when I see in `network` is something like:

```
http://domainName:8080/users/findUser/1234
```

API call fails at `OPTIONS` itself and error I am receiving from backend is

```
Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403
```

It never reaches `POST`.

`token` is retrieved from `localstorage` and is something like `Bearer eyJhbGci...`.

Backend developers are using Java and Spring .

Is there something wrong in the way I am calling the APIs or this problem should be resolved in the Backend?

This API works totally fine when tested through Postman.

Comment: This is possibly a CORS issue, when you make a request via Postman, do you see any `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers in the response?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there is already a solution for this problem in the backend :

[How to configure CORS in a Spring Boot + Spring Security application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968963/how-to-configure-cors-in-a-spring-boot-spring-security-application/37610988#37610988)

It works like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

'headers' always come as 3rd parameter in POST request of axios. Give 2nd arguement if there is any or pass 2nd parameter as empty String.