# How configure Spring boot CORS for Restful API?

Tags: spring, reactjs, cors

I've used thi s guide (https://medium.com/emblatech/secure-your-spring-restful-apis-with-jwt-a-real-world-example-bfdd2679db5f) to secure RestFull API.

But now I've a CORS problem  when I try to connect from a REACT JS app.

This is my configuration:

**AuthorizationServerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${security.jwt.client-id}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${security.jwt.client-secret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Value("${security.jwt.grant-type}")
    private String grantType;

    @Value("${security.jwt.grant-type-refresh}")
    private String grantTypeRefresh;

    @Value("${security.jwt.scope-read}")
    private String scopeRead;

    @Value("${security.jwt.scope-write}")
    private String scopeWrite = "write";

    @Value("${security.jwt.resource-ids}")
    private String resourceIds;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl")
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient(clientId)
                .secret("{noop}"+clientSecret)
                .authorizedGrantTypes(grantType, grantTypeRefresh)
                .scopes(scopeRead, scopeWrite)
                .resourceIds(resourceIds);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenServices(defaultTokenServices).authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter).userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

}
```

**ResourceServerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices;

    @Value("${security.jwt.resource-ids}")
    private String resourceIds;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId(resourceIds).tokenServices(tokenServices);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .requestMatchers()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/**").authenticated();
    }

}
```

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${security.signing-key}")
    private String signingKey;

    @Value("${security.security-realm}")
    private String securityRealm;

    @Value("${security.jwt.token-validity-seconds}")
    private int accessTokenValiditySeconds;

    @Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl")
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
                .realmName(securityRealm)
            .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey(signingKey);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain() {
        final TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(new MyTokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));
        return tokenEnhancerChain;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        defaultTokenServices.setAccessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenValiditySeconds);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    private static class MyTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer {
        @Override
        public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return accessToken;
        }
    }

}
```

In every call i do i receive this error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/test 401
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/test' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I've also already tride some solution explained here for example: [How to configure CORS in a Spring Boot + Spring Security application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968963/how-to-configure-cors-in-a-spring-boot-spring-security-application)

But nothing works for me.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add Cors Configuration to your application, so that it can accept AJAX requests from a different domain. Whether such requests are sent by react or angular or jquery, the server will still behave the same way.

The easiest way to accept CORS in your Spring Boot application is to add the following annotation to your Controller classes :

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="*")
```

Please beware, however, that when you use the wildcard (*), your service will accept Ajax requests from **any** domain, which is not secure. You might want to replace the wildcard by the specific domains that you want to accept requests from.

Repeating the annotation in all your controllers might be annoying and error-prone. Instead, you may use one the configuration solutions described in [How to configure CORS in a Spring Boot + Spring Security application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968963/how-to-configure-cors-in-a-spring-boot-spring-security-application) or follow Spring documentation about [CORS configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#cors)