# Spring security Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * (CORS) issue on invalid JWT token

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, microservices

I have JWT security configured with Spring Security in Spring Boot application. I have an issue with

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

header, also known as CORS. I configured application so header is present in every server response but once JWT token invalid, server responses with 403 error code without Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header. This leads browser to write error message to console:

> Failed to load http://... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://...' is therefore
>   not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

**It seems wrong and I would like to get Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header in response, even though JWT token invalid and server responses with 403 error code.**

Now what I tried and my code.

Dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
...

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

As I understood this issue could be caused by filter order in filter chain, and I tried to put my JWT JwtAuthenticationFilter after CorsFilter or CsrfFilter, create CorsConfigurationSource bean. This described at https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#cors and discussed at [How to configure CORS in a Spring Boot + Spring Security application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968963/how-to-configure-cors-in-a-spring-boot-spring-security-application) and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5834, but nothing seems helps

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${com.faircloud.common.security.header}")
    private String header;
    @Value("${com.faircloud.common.security.prefix}")
    private String prefix;
    @Value("${com.faircloud.common.security.validateLink}")
    private String validateLink;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/**",
                        "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**")
                .permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .addFilterAfter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(header, prefix, validateLink),
                        CsrfFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(ImmutableList.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(ImmutableList.of("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        // setAllowCredentials(true) is important, otherwise:
        // The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must
        // not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        // setAllowedHeaders is important! Without it, OPTIONS preflight request
        // will fail with 403 Invalid CORS request
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(ImmutableList.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Here the JwtAuthenticationFilter class. Please note, to validate token it calls other microservice over http. Also my application does not have login endpoint, because login implemented on other microservice application.

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    private String header;
    private String prefix;
    private String validateLink;

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(String header, String prefix, String validateLink) {
        super(new AuthenticationManager() {
            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException{
                return null;
            }
        });
        this.header = header;
        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.validateLink = validateLink;
    } 

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response, 
            FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        // 1. get the authentication header. Tokens are supposed to be passed in the
        // authentication header
        String headerValue = request.getHeader(header);

        // 2. validate the header and check the prefix
        if (headerValue == null || !headerValue.startsWith(prefix)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response); // If not valid, go to the next filter.
            return;
        }
        // 3. Get the token     
        String token = headerValue.replace(prefix, ""); 

        try {

            GatewayResponse gatewayResponse = validate(token);

            String userId = gatewayResponse.getUserId();

            /*
            Roles could come from gateway or loaded from current
            microservice database by user id. They are
            hardcoded here to illustrate how to populate
            SecurityContextHolder
            */
            List<String> authorities = new LinkedList<String>();
            authorities.add("USER");
            authorities.add("ADMIN");

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userId, null,
                    authorities.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toList()));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            addTokenToResponse(gatewayResponse.getAuthHeader(), response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // In case of failure. Make sure it's clear; so guarantee user won't be
            // authenticated
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        }

        // go to the next filter in the filter chain
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private void addTokenToResponse(String authHeaderValue, HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.addHeader(header, prefix+authHeaderValue);
    }

    private GatewayResponse validate(String token) {
        /HTTP call here, returns null if invalid token
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

having similar issue, couldn't make it working with CorsConfigurationSource. Only filter based CORS support helped:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
    final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();

    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");

    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);

    return bean;
}
```

Comment: Setting highest precedence for the CorsFilter in the filterchain worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the CrosFilter. Find the below sample.

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("HEAD");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```