# Google App Engine and CORS Error (Java server)

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, cors

Frontend running on App Egnine

I have a simple java app for my backend hosted on Google App Engine.

I get this error while trying to reach any endpoints in app engine. `Access to fetch at 'backendURL' from origin 'frontendURL' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

However when I test it locally, everything works fine. My assumption is there is an issue with the app.yaml for the backend.

Here is my app.yaml file:

```
runtime: java11
instance_class: F2

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: auto

automatic_scaling:
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.65
```

Here is my java code for CORS:

```
    private static void enableCORS() {
        Spark.options("/*",
                (request, response) -> {

                    String accessControlRequestHeaders = request
                            .headers("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
                    if (accessControlRequestHeaders != null) {
                        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                                accessControlRequestHeaders);
                    }

                    String accessControlRequestMethod = request
                            .headers("Access-Control-Request-Method");
                    if (accessControlRequestMethod != null) {
                        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                                accessControlRequestMethod);
                    }

                    return "OK";
                });

        Spark.before((request, response) -> response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"));
    }
```

I have already spent much time trying to fix it, [even followed the answer for the same issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64592688/cors-error-in-google-app-engine-on-java-server)

I tried this, but as mentioned in the other forum I would get the error `Unexpected attribute "http_headers" for mapping type script.`:

```
runtime: java11
instance_class: F2

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
    http_headers:
      Access-Contrl-ALlow-Origin: "*"

automatic_scaling:
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.65
```

Could someone help me to solve this problem?