# Spring Boot - CORS filter works for GET, but not for other HTTP Verbs

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, cors

I am working in a Spring Boot 2.2.5 application with an Angular 9 frontend.

I have been trying to configure a CORS filter on the Spring Boot backend to allow any origin with any headers for any request.

Based on my research, what I currently have implemented in my main `Application.java` file should work:

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

However, what I am experiencing is that this is only allowing me to execute `GET` call from the frontend to my controller on the backend. Any other call to `POST` or `PUT` fails with the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/spring-boot-starter-seed/default-theme/save/cyan' from origin 'http://localhost:8083' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I know im somewhat on the right track because if I remove the `@Bean` I implemented, then all calls from frontend to backend fail due to that error. But when implementing that Bean, for some reason its only working for `GET` requests.

Is there something I have missed?

***** Update *****

I dont know if this will be helpful, but, I am using Azure AD for authentication with this application. I have a `WebSecurityConfig` that looks like this:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter grantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles");
        grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");

        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedAuthoritiesConverter);
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**", "/heartbeat/**", "/register", "/unregister").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(this.jwtAuthenticationConverter());
    }
}
```

Earlier in my post I said that `GET` requests are working, but that seems to be somewhat false.

`GET /heartbeat` works. However...

`GET /default-theme` does not work and fails with the same No Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.

The only difference between these two Controller paths is that the `/default-theme` is not included in the excluded antMatchers, and it is protected by `@PreAuthorize(value = "hasRole('ROLE_access')")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as it turns out, my update on my original post was on the right track to assume that Spring Security and my `WebSecurityConfig` was part of the cause.

I found the real solution on an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968963/how-to-configure-cors-in-a-spring-boot-spring-security-application).

I needed to update my `HttpSecurity` config to include the `.cors()` first:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**", "/heartbeat", "/register", "/unregister").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt()
            .jwtAuthenticationConverter(this.jwtAuthenticationConverter());
}
```

***After doing this, all other CORS configurations were unnecessary and could be removed from my app. Just add the `@CrossOrigin` annotation to any relevant controllers.***

With this in place, calling my `GET /default-theme` controller, protected by the `@PreAuthorize(value = "hasRole('ROLE_access')")`, got rid of the No Access-Control-Allow-Origin error, and resulted in the error I expected which was a 401 response.

The underlying reason for all of this was because I was tasked with migrating this application from LDAP auth to Azure AD auth.

Hopefully this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

### I think the problem here is due to the filter of the dispatcher servlet :

try this class to implement a filter as well :

```
public class CORSFilter extends GenericFilterBean implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chaine)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse)response;
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "false");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        System.out.println("****************** CORS Configuration Completed *******************");
        chaine.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Then inject the bean in your main application class or every where  :

```
@Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean crosFilterRegistration(){
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CORSFilter());
        registrationBean.setName("CORS Filter");
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        registrationBean.setOrder(1);
        return registrationBean;
    }
```

Hope this would be helpfull

Comment: Amanoun, I tried what you provided, but it is the same result. I have updated my post with additional information.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `WebSecurityConfig` class you need to configure `cors` as given below

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
     ...
     .and()
     .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
     .and()
     ...
}
```

```java
@Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(
                "list of domains here"
                )
        );
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("DELETE", "GET", "POST", "PATCH", "PUT", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(
                Arrays.asList(
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                        "Access-Control-Request-Method",
                        "Access-Control-Request-Headers",
                        "Origin", "Cache-Control",
                        "Content-Type",
                        "Authorization"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```