# Angular requests blocked by CORS policy only under certain conditions

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

Hi I've created an Angular app with a Spring Boot/Spring Security backend using this guide:

https://www.javaguides.net/2019/04/spring-boot-spring-security-angular-example-tutorial.html

In my Controller class I have the following simple method to request:

```
    @GetMapping("/test/{gameId}")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    public ResponseMessage test(@PathVariable int gameId) {
        return new ResponseMessage("HelloMessage", "Hello there id=" + gameId);
    }
```

I've added a .permitAll() to the test route:

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/**")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/test/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
```

On my Angular frontend I have a simple method on the homepage to test the method:

```
  doSomething() {
    console.log("Doing something...");
    this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/test/75154").subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

**Problem 1: CORS policy error when both logged in and page is refreshed**

If I run my page and click the button as a logged-out user, I get the expected response:

```
{type: "HelloMessage", message: "Hello there id=75154", data: null}
```

If I then log in, return to the home page and click the button again, the response still works.
The problem is when I refresh the page - I am still logged in, but now requests are blocked by CORS policy:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/test/75154' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
zone-evergreen.js:2845 GET http://localhost:8080/test/75154 net::ERR_FAILED
core.js:4352 ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:8080/test/75154", ok: false, …}
error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/test/75154: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://localhost:8080/test/75154"
```

If I click logout and return to the homepage, I can once again receive requests from the backend without this error message. POSTMAN can receive the requests as well.

**Problem 2: Securing /test also gives CORS errors rather than unauthorised response**
If I remove the 2 lines from the configure method to permitAll the test path, I get the expected response in POSTMAN that the path is now unauthorised:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-01-08T12:05:54.665+00:00",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/test/5"
}
```

However, in the Angular app itself I'm getting CORS policy errors instead of the unauthorised JSON. I can log in and get the correct response, but I still have issue with problem 1 whereby refreshing the page returns the CORS policy error. Again, logging out then logging back in will fix the issue until the page is refreshed.

The HttpInterceptor and AuthService classes are as shown in the guide in the link above.

Comment: Can you please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65514482/spring-boot-cors-filter-works-for-get-but-not-for-other-http-verbs/65519895#65519895

Comment: Thanks for the link, that seemed to fix the issue with getting CORS errors instead of unauthorised response.

Comment: You can mark it as an accepted answer or upvote if it helps you,

Comment: I think my account is still too pleb to upvote, otherwise I would!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloaded tutorial and it was working out of the box.

Now to the problem, it is possible to recreate the problem without adding your code by performing a hard refresh of the Hello World page after login.

The reason for this, is that the author of this tutorial has not included code for storing credentials in `localStorage`. Hence, when page is reloaded, client app looses credentials stored in state, and pre-flight requests are denied which in turn causes CORS-error.

So, there is no error, just some code missing in order to make it work according to your requirements.

Maybe ask a new question on how to persist credentials to localStorage in Angular (I'm not that good with Angular).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have added this but the app still responds in the same way.

Comment: Of course, though I'm not sure what is causing the issue. Shouldn't the app still be in the same state after a refresh, and why would it give a CORS error rather than an auth error when POSTMAN received the correct response?

Comment: @whereami: Sorry for the delay, I had to install Angular on this computer. I found your problem, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for going to the trouble. It looks like you can store simply by using localStorage instead of sessionStorage with same method names. silentsudo's link above removed the issue with CORS and I now get the authentication error as expected, although this is still a problem after refreshing as it is no longer authorised. I think I need a way of persisting the token perhaps.

Comment: @whereami: Looked into silentsudo's link. If you get the localStorage fixed, you shouldn't have to add more CORS stuff than already in project.