# Why Spring Security did not add Access-Control-Allow-Origin for GET request with a Request Header?

Tags: java, angular, spring, cors

My goal is to debug why I can send HTTP GET request without `RequestHeaders`, but I can't send HTTP GET request with `RequestHeaders`, on browser.

I am following the [spring.io's tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#how-does-it-work) to learn more about CSRF and CORS.

What I've tried:

1. Send GET Request to `http://localhost:8080/user` with Request Header `Authorization: Basic .....` would return me CORS error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/user' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

2. SEND GET Request to `http://localhost:8080/user` without a Request Header will not return me an CORS error.

Note: I've double check that CORS issue is resolved for any GET request if I did not add Request Header.

```
  @Bean
  CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
  }
```

However, it does not fix CORS issue if I send the `GET /user` with a Request Header `Authorization: Basic ....`

My expected result is: When I send a GET request with a Request Header, it should not return a CORS error.

My actual result is: It return a CORS error.

Comment: Do you have different configs for "Authorized"  and public URL ?

Comment: @gvmani I only override `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method from the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class. The Angular project and the Spring Security project lives on different port. Please feel free to clone [the full repository](https://github.com/kidfrom/learn-java/tree/main/etc/spring-security-angular).

Comment: this question might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968963/how-to-configure-cors-in-a-spring-boot-spring-security-application

Answer (score 0):

If you use JDK 8+, there is a one solution:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
}
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: I checked the `applyPermitDefaultValues()` source code. It should works. I decided to manually configure it [Spring Security's Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/cors.html).