# Cross Origin Issue in Spring Boot and Angular Application

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

Well i have to integrate Spring with Angular , wrt to implement this im getting Cros Policy issue and for this regard i have already added @CrossOrigin annotation in the Rest controller.
Below is my code

**my Rest Controller**

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:9001", "http://localhost:4200"},allowedHeaders = "*")
public class PatientVisitRestController {
    
    @Autowired
    PatientVisitService patientVisitService;
    
    
    @PostMapping("/patient/add")
    public String savePatientVisit(@RequestBody PatientVisit patientVisit)
    {
        
        patientVisitService.addPatientVisit(patientVisit);
        
        return "Saved := "+patientVisit.getPatientName()+" - "+patientVisit.getSlipNumber();
        
    }

    @GetMapping("/patient/phone/{ph}")
    public List<PatientVisit> getPatientbyPhone(@PathVariable long ph)
    {
        List<PatientVisit> list =  patientVisitService.getPatientVisitByPhoneNumber(ph);
        return list;
    }
    
    
    
}  //end controller


@SpringBootApplication
public class OpdPatientConsoleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OpdPatientConsoleApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**and Below is my Angular Service**

```
import { PatientDetails } from './patient-details';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PatientService {

  contextPath:string= 'http://localhost:9001';
  // tomcatServerContentRoot = 'http://localhost:8081';
  endPoint_getPatientsByPhone:string =  this.contextPath+'/patient/phone/';
  
 
  http:HttpClient;
     
  constructor(http:HttpClient) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  getPatientsByPhone(phone:number):Observable<PatientDetails[]>
  {
    let endPoint_getPatientsByPhone = this.contextPath+'/patient/phone/'+phone;
    console.log("--->> Patient Service : searchPatientsByPhone endpoint :- "+endPoint_getPatientsByPhone);
    return this.http.get<PatientDetails[]>(`${this.endPoint_getPatientsByPhone}`);
  }


}
```

***And below is the error screen pic***

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure CORS in a Spring Boot + Spring Security application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968963/how-to-configure-cors-in-a-spring-boot-spring-security-application)

Answer (score -2):

One way to solve this problem is to set up a proxy for your local development. To do this, create a "proxy.conf.json" in your root directory.

```js
{
  "/patient": {
    "target": "http://localhost:9001",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Start your application with: "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json".

For a full example take a look [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d).