# How to authorize CORS in Spring Security filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I'm trying to build a REST API with Spring Boot and Spring Security but I have run into an issue where any request to the `/login` endpoint is blocked because of `CORS` and I can't figure out how to allow it.

Here's what I get when I inspect the network tab of my developper tools whenever I send a login request in my frontend application:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here's my `SecurityConfig.java` file (I've omitted imports for brevity):

```
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final AuthenticationUserDetailService authenticationUserDetailService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String jwtSecret;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.cors();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/teachers/**").hasAuthority("TEACHER");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/students/**").hasAuthority("STUDENT");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN");

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        //http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
        http.addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtSecret));
        http.addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtSecret));
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(authenticationUserDetailService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

Here's my `JwtAuthenticationFilter.java` file:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final String jwtSecret;

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, String jwtSecret) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.jwtSecret = jwtSecret;
        setFilterProcessesUrl("/login");
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            LoginRequest credentials = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(request.getInputStream(), LoginRequest.class);

            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            credentials.getUsername(),
                            credentials.getPassword(),
                            new ArrayList<>())
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        User user = (User) authResult.getPrincipal();

        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret.getBytes())
                .claim("role", authResult.getAuthorities().iterator().next().getAuthority())
                .setSubject(user.getUsername())
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 24 * 3600 * 1000))
                .compact();

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write("{\"token\":\"" + token + "\"}");
    }
}
```

I have tried every solution I have found online and I'm out of ideas. How can I authorize CORS from any source for my `/login` endpoint ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you post your login controller? there are 2 issues here. 1. CORS issues which you are facing because your UI is making an OPTIONS call before actual POST call. 2. 403 which should not ideally be there because you excluded /login in ant matcher. so just want to cross check

Comment: @SridharPatnaik I have no login controller. Everything is in the JwtAuthenticationFilter class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure CORS in a Spring Boot + Spring Security application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968963/how-to-configure-cors-in-a-spring-boot-spring-security-application)

Comment: CORS is the most answered question when it comes to spring security. We get about 5 questions a week about it. Please use the search function before asking. The spring security document has an entire chapter about CORS and there are literally 100s of answers here when it comes to CORS. Voted to close duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a Bean of type `CorsConfigurationSource` and tell Spring Security to use that configuration source in the `CorsFilter`, and place it before the authentication and authorization filters.

First, define the `CorsConfigurationSource` Bean:

```java
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return source;
}
```

Then, tell Spring Security to configure CORS with defaults:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    ...
    http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults());
    ...
}
```