# Spring Authorization Server with AuthorizationGrantType.PASSWORD

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I want to build an authorization server with Spring Authorization Server project. For now I want to use AuthorizationGrantType.PASSWORD.

I developed a demo project from the samples of Spring Authorization Server project. However, when I try to get token with the *http://localhost:9000/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&username=user&password=pass* (I'm using client_id and client_secret as basic auth in Postman) request, I'm getting 403.

What I'm missing here?

**Dependencies**: *spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-starter-security, spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server (version: 0.2.2)*

**AuthorizationServerConfig class:**

```
import java.security.*;
import java.security.interfaces.*;
import java.util.UUID;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.*;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.*;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.ProviderSettings;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.*;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;

@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class AuthorizationServerConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("client1")
                .clientSecret("{noop}secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.PASSWORD)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .build();
        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ProviderSettings providerSettings() {
        return ProviderSettings.builder()
                .issuer("http://auth-server:9000")
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        RSAKey rsaKey = generateRsa();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return (jwkSelector, securityContext) -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet);
    }
    
    private static RSAKey generateRsa() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        return new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
    }
    
    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }    
}
```

**DefaultSecurityConfig class:**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.*;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class DefaultSecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().disable()
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests
                                .anyRequest()
                                .authenticated()
                );
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails userDetails = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("pass")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }    
}
```

There is this message in the log that I found It may be related:

```
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [POST /oauth2/token?grant_type=password&username=user&password=pass] with attributes [authenticated]
```

Comment: Most likely CORS, Does this answer your question? [How to configure CORS in a Spring Boot + Spring Security application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968963/how-to-configure-cors-in-a-spring-boot-spring-security-application)

Comment: @Toerktumlare No. I disabled the CORS and I got the same response. Also I'm able to use "../auth2/authorize" endpoint, so it shouldn't be related with CORS. I also added a log message to post that I found it may be related.

Comment: grant type is password so you need to authenticate with username and password.

Comment: client_id:clientId
grant_type:password
username:username
password:password
scope:read,write

Comment: @shadows did you find a way to handle password grant?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like password grant_type is not supported. Probably that's why I was getting error.

source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/126

Answer (score 4):

I need that grant in my applications even if it was deprecated. I think that when we manage our own clients, it makes sens to use that grant. I managed to add it by following [this guide in the official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/guides/how-to-ext-grant-type.html). It took me 2 hours to implement it and test it.

EDIT: Take a look at my [gist](https://gist.github.com/akuma8/2eb244b796f3d3506956207997fb290f) to see the implementation.

Comment: does it worked ? can you share your source code will help a lot

Comment: @chaitanya yes it works, I will share my code tonight.

Comment: @chaitanya as promised I updated my answer to add the source code

Comment: thank it worked !, but can you help me with the getting refresh token as well with the access token.

Comment: @chaitanya you can modify the original code to also add a refresh token, in my case I did not need a refresh token

Comment: @chaitanya Did you succeed on adding the refresh token? I needed to add it so I updated OAuth2PasswordGrantAuthenticationProvider to add it. It's a bit tricky above all we need to add a json mixin for OAuth2PasswordGrantAuthenticationToken but I managed to implement it. When I will have time, I will update my gist to add the solution.

Comment: yes @akuma8, I did able to add refresh token by following this guy

https://github.com/wdkeyser02/SpringBootOAuth2/blob/part16/SpringBootOauth2AuthorizationServer/src/main/java/willydekeyser/config/CustomPassordAuthenticationProvider.java