# Java / Angular API call

Tags: java, angular, spring

I have a backend in java Spring :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getLogin(@RequestBody Credential credential) {
    System.out.println("Hello moto");
    System.out.println(credential.toString());
    return "Allo";
}
```

I have my front in Angular with which I make my API call:

```
 login() {
const body = {"email": "string", "password": "string"}
this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/login/', {
  "email": "string",
  "password": "string"
}, {responseType: 'json'}).pipe(map(user => {
  console.log("user : ", user);
}));
console.log("userService")
```

}

My console.log is displayed fine when I click on the button.
I manage to make the calls with PostMan I have the answer.. But I can't get it via Angular, do you have any solutions to offer me?

Thanks

Comment: What does _"can't get it"_ mean, exactly? I'd guess a CORS problem, which you should research (and note making the request to localhost means this only works on your machine).

Comment: It works on my machine with Postman, but using my browser I can't make the API call. What do you mean by a CORS problem? Cordially

Comment: have to enable CORS from the backend!

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console or in the network tab?

Comment: I have no errors in the console

Comment: How to enable cors @TaimoorQureshi ? `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")`

Comment: you can find out on this platform. the following link could be helpful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968963/how-to-configure-cors-in-a-spring-boot-spring-security-application

Comment: It looks like you are not subscribing to the observable returned from the http client. Therefore no request is made to your backend.