# Can't configure Cors on java spring / vue js

Tags: javascript, java, vue.js, cors

I have controller like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/country/")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8082")
public class CountryController {
    private final CountryService countryService;

    @GetMapping("getAll")
    public ResponseEntity<GetAllCountriesResponse> getAllCountries() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(countryService.getAllCountriesResponse());
    }
}
```

and i'm trying to send request from vue js app on http://localhost:8082/ to server on http://localhost:8081/

like so

axios("http://localhost:8081/api/v1/country/getAll")

when i'm using postman everything is fine, but when i try to do this in vue js i get

Acess to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8081/api/v1/country/getAll' from origin 'http://localhost:8082' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

How can i configure this on spring v3.0.1

Comment: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968963/how-to-configure-cors-in-a-spring-boot-spring-security-application