# Angular + Spring. CORS policy

Tags: spring, cors

I have get requests working, but post requests to the server are not working
[image]

I'll keep it short. I'm using Spring Cloud
From Angular I send a request to Gateway(8082) and it redirects to the microservice I need.

What I've tried so far:

1. `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` I put it over each controller
2. Writing a config class. I've been overhauling this config as much as I can.

   ```
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
   import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
   import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
   import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

   @Configuration

   @EnableWebMvc

   public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

       @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
           registry.addMapping("/auth/user/**") // Specificare il percorso dell'API
                   .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200") // Fonte autorizzata.
                   .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8202") // Fonte autorizzata.
                   .allowedMethods("GET") // Metodi autorizzati
                   .allowedMethods("POST") // Metodi autorizzati
                   .allowedMethods("PUT") // Metodi autorizzati
                   .allowedMethods("DELETE") // Metodi autorizzati
                   .allowCredentials(true); // Consentire l'invio di cookie e intestazioni di autorizzazione
       }
   }
   ```

3. Created the proxy.conf.ts file:

   ```
   {
     "/finance/*": {
       "target": "http://localhost:8082",
       "secure": false
     },
     "/auth/*": {
       "target": "http://localhost:8082",
       "secure": false
     }
   }
   ```

But still post requests through postman I can send, but through angular I can't:(

Comment: The code didn't insert nicely for some reason :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure CORS in a Spring Boot + Spring Security application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968963/how-to-configure-cors-in-a-spring-boot-spring-security-application)

Comment: Here are a few (4116) other questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=spring+cors

Comment: If you don't understand why Postman works but Angular doesn't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

Neither calls to method [`allowedOrigins`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/74175c1117e6ffd10c48e3c1339efed5db5fdd85/spring-webflux/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/config/CorsRegistration.java#L58) nor calls to method [`allowedMethods`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/74175c1117e6ffd10c48e3c1339efed5db5fdd85/spring-webflux/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/config/CorsRegistration.java#L83) have *cumulative* effects; instead, the last call to each method prevails. In other words, your CORS configuration,

```java
registry.addMapping("/auth/user/**")
  .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
  .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8202") // only this call counts
  .allowedMethods("GET")
  .allowedMethods("POST")
  .allowedMethods("PUT")
  .allowedMethods("DELETE") // only this call counts
  .allowCredentials(true);
}
```

is equivalent to the following:

```java
registry.addMapping("/auth/user/**")
  .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8202")
  .allowedMethods("DELETE")
  .allowCredentials(true);
```

Your client's Web origin, `http://localhost:4200`, is therefore not allowed by your CORS configuration; as a result, preflight fails.

### Solution

Be aware that methods `allowedOrigins` and `allowedMethods` are variadic. Therefore, you should write the following instead:

```java
registry.addMapping("/auth/user/**")
  .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:8202")
  .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
  .allowCredentials(true);
}
```

However, because `http://localhost:8202` is the Web origin of your server (AFAICT), you shouldn't need to list it as an allowed origin in your CORS configuration.