# CORS filter disable not working spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors

I'm configuring my security this way:

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

    final DelegatingJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter authoritiesConverter = new DelegatingJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(
            // First add the default converter
            new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(),
            // Second add our custom Keycloak specific converter
            new KeycloakJwtRolesConverter());

    // Set up http security to use the JWT converter defined above
    httpSecurity

            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 ->
                    oauth2.jwt(jwtCustomizer -> {
                                jwtCustomizer.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthConvertor ->
                                        new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwtAuthConvertor,
                                                authoritiesConverter.convert(jwtAuthConvertor)));
                                jwtCustomizer.jwkSetUri(jwkUri);
                            }
                    )
            )
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers(SECURED_URLS).hasAuthority("ROLE_realm_user")
                    .requestMatchers(SWAGGER_UI_URLS)
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

    return httpSecurity.build();
}
```

and this is the URL which should be secured by some role

```
    private static final RequestMatcher SECURED_URLS = new OrRequestMatcher(
        AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/mySecuredURL/**")
);
```

I'm also disabling the cors check in the same method.

and when I'm doing the request from angular application, which is running on another port, I'm getting 401 and this error:

```
Referrer Policy:strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

this is due to cors check.
and when I'm doing the request from swagger or postman, the request succesfully comes to server and behaves as expected.
Now when I change the secured url like "/api1/mySecuredURL1/**"
Ideally it should restric the access and not let the request come in, since for this url I have configured some role, but

1. it lets the request in and precess the request (not expected behavior)
2. for the request from angular, it should let in, but it doesn't(not expected behavior)

and this is my RoleConvertor class

```
    public class KeycloakJwtRolesConverter implements Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {
    /**
     * Prefix used for realm level roles.
     */
    public static final String PREFIX_REALM_ROLE = "ROLE_realm_";
    /**
     * Prefix used in combination with the resource (client) name for resource level roles.
     */
    public static final String PREFIX_RESOURCE_ROLE = "ROLE_";

    /**
     * Name of the claim containing the realm level roles
     */
    private static final String CLAIM_REALM_ACCESS = "realm_access";
    /**
     * Name of the claim containing the resources (clients) the user has access to.
     */
    private static final String CLAIM_RESOURCE_ACCESS = "resource_access";
    /**
     * Name of the claim containing roles. (Applicable to realm and resource level.)
     */
    private static final String CLAIM_ROLES = "roles";


    /**
     * Extracts the realm and resource level roles from a JWT token distinguishing between them using prefixes.
     */
    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> convert(final Jwt jwt) {
        // Collection that will hold the extracted roles
        final Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();

        // Realm roles
        // Get the part of the access token that holds the roles assigned on realm level
        final Map<String, Collection<String>> realmAccess = jwt.getClaim(CLAIM_REALM_ACCESS);

        // Verify that the claim exists and is not empty
        if (realmAccess != null && !realmAccess.isEmpty()) {
            // From the realm_access claim get the roles
            final Collection<String> roles = realmAccess.get(CLAIM_ROLES);
            // Check if any roles are present
            if (roles != null && !roles.isEmpty()) {
                final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> realmRoles = roles.stream()
                        // Prefix all realm roles with "ROLE_realm_"
                        .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(PREFIX_REALM_ROLE + role))
                        .toList();
                grantedAuthorities.addAll(realmRoles);
            }
        }

        final Map<String, Map<String, Collection<String>>> resourceAccess = jwt.getClaim(CLAIM_RESOURCE_ACCESS);

        if (resourceAccess != null && !resourceAccess.isEmpty()) {
            resourceAccess.forEach((resource, resourceClaims) -> resourceClaims.get(CLAIM_ROLES).forEach(
                    role -> grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(PREFIX_RESOURCE_ROLE + resource + "_" + role))
            ));
        }
        return grantedAuthorities;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't disable CORS in your backend app and hope that the browser thinks it's ok. In the end you need to provide the browser with the correct headers so that the browser allows your frontend to send calls to your backend.

Comment: ok, can you please show me the way of configuring this, I'm using a bounch of ways, but still no success.

Comment: Yes! Follow Honzas excellent answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This is a misunderstanding what CORS is.

You need to understand that CORS handling is a **browser** feature, not *any* client feature, and it is not a server feature.

It is your browser who checks that a site requests a resource whose URL is cross-origin (a different protocol, a different domain, or a different port). This is built-in to the browsers, to protect the client against evil sites pretending they are someone else and trying to fetch resources from genuine backend services.

When your site requests a resource from backend, your browser communicates with the server and asks it, if it allows CORS. If yes, the browser is happy and continues, otherwise you get an error.

You have never CORS problem when calling the request from POSTMAN, because there is no originating site, so the request *cannot* be cross-origin.

By calling `cors().disable()` you are not disabling the CORS check on the server, but you are configuring the server to tell the client that cross-origin requests are forbidden.

What you really need are two options:

1. The better option is to write your web site in a way that you do not need to handle CORS. In other words, call backend services only in the same protocol/domain/port as your web page is.
2. If it is really necessary, you need to configure your server to **enable** CORS, not to disable it.

There are many sites describing it, try e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors or [How to configure CORS in a Spring Boot + Spring Security application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36968963/2886891)

Comment: ok, so can you suggest here a solution?

Comment: See my edit. But give some time to understand what CORS is before you start coding.

Comment: _Cross-origin_, not _cross-site_. The distinction is [subtle but crucial](https://jub0bs.com/posts/2021-01-29-great-samesite-confusion/).

Comment: Also, you wrote: _you are configuring the server to tell the client that cross-origin requests are forbidden._ That's misleading; not enabling CORS does _not_ block all cross-origin requests. Browsers will agree to send so-called _simple_ requests without batting an eyelid. Try executing `fetch("//example.com")` in your browser's Console tab from this very page: there will be a CORS error, but only after the browser has already sent the request.

Comment: @jub0bs thanks for your correction. You are right. However, I just wanted to give the OP the global picture to correct his more deep misunderstanding, especially what cors().disable() means.