# Spring Security 6: cors() is deprecated and marked for removal

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have this code below:

```
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/register")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/users")
            .hasAnyAuthority("USER", "ADMIN")
            .and().formLogin().and().build();
}
```

Please help me in making this feature work

Comment: Those spring security methods are being changed to take lambdas to configure them instead of using that fluent style.

Comment: See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#cors()) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#cors(org.springframework.security.config.Customizer)).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure CORS in a Spring Boot + Spring Security application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968963/how-to-configure-cors-in-a-spring-boot-spring-security-application)

Answer (score 3):

According to [Migration Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html) and also [configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/migration-7/configuration.html) to newest version, the `securityFilterChain` should have next one body.

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> {
          request.requestMatchers("/register").permitAll();
          request.requestMatchers("/users")
              .hasAnyAuthority("USER", "ADMIN");
        }).formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();

  }
```

Also please read/check from above references to documentation.
By the way here on stack overflow are many posts about migration to newest version of framework.

Answer (score 3):

We need to configure beans as below.

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(httpSecurityCorsConfigurer -> httpSecurityCorsConfigurer.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .requestMatchers("/myAccount", "/myBalance", "/myLoans", "/myCards", "/user").authenticated()
                .requestMatchers("/contacts", "/notices", "/register").permitAll()
        );
        http.formLogin(withDefaults());
        http.httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
```

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
    //Make the below setting as * to allow connection from any hos
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:4200"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
    corsConfiguration.setMaxAge(3600L);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
    return source;
}
```

Comment: Fixed the coding style

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

```
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(c -> c.requestMatchers("/register").permitAll().requestMatchers("/users").hasAnyAuthority("USER", "ADMIN"))
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .build();
}
```