'sessionManagement()','and()','csrf()','cors()' is deprecated since version 6.1 and marked for removal this fix it
This is my AppConfig file. How can I resolve 'sessionManagement()','and()','csrf()','cors()' is deprecated since version 6.1 and marked for removal?
 @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()

                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthFilter(jwtProvider), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers(PERMIT_URL_ARRAY).permitAll()
                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();

        return http.build();
    }

I want to fix this to Spring Security 6.x version
Please help me

You can find out your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77266685/spring-security-6-cors-is-deprecated-and-marked-for-removal
