# how to set CORS in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, http, spring-security, cors

I have react app on `localhost:3000` and trying to make axios request in spring boot `localhost:8080`. I am using spring boot security, and enabled the `cors()` on httpFilter and then add annotation of `@CorssOrigin("http://localhost:3000")` above the controller:

*SecurityConfig.java*:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthFilter authFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(req -> req
                        .requestMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .addFilterBefore(authFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}

*AuthController*:
@RestController
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:3000")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuthController {
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private UserService userService;
    private JwtService jwtService;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<RegisterDtoout> register(@RequestBody RegisterDtoin registerDtoin) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.createUser(registerDtoin));
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody LoginDto loginDto) {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                 new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                         loginDto.getUsername(),
                         loginDto.getPassword()
                 )
        );
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String token = jwtService.createToken(authentication.getName());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(token);
    }
}
```

but when making the axios request

```
axios.post(REGISTER_URL, {
      username: user,
      password: pwd
    }, { withCredentials: true })
```

The firefox logs errors:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/register. (Reason: expected ‘true’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Credentials’).

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/register. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

So I guess the spring boot did not send `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`?

Comment: This gets asked 3 times a day, please use the search function and there is an entire chapter on CORS in the spring security docs [How to configure CORS in a Spring Boot + Spring Security application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968963/how-to-configure-cors-in-a-spring-boot-spring-security-application) also handing out JWT tokens to browsers is not recommended and there is a reason to why that type of authentication does not exists in spring security. please read the docs and not poor blogs/tutorials that dont know how security works

Comment: *So I guess the spring boot did not send Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true?* Yes, because you didn't configure it. You have to configure it.

Comment: no you dont, please read the oauth2 specification before you ask. Because i cant teach you security in some comments. JWTs were never supposed to be used as sessions. If you use a private client your backend authenticates with google etc and then keeps the jwt in the backend and gives a cookie to the browser. If you use oauth2, you use a BFF pattern that will auth with your issuer and hand out a AT token, a RT token and an ID token, and when you call the backend you have a token proxy that will exchange the cookie for a jwt, and the JWT is only used within the private network.

Comment: absolutely everyone that hands out JWTs to browsers have not read the oauth2 spec, the OWASP recommendations, Springs own recommendations and have no idea how security works. They have only read other blogs and then written their own take on what some other blog wrote. And then people read it and thinks that thats how security works.

Comment: So you are saying you should authenticate with Google or rely on third party token provider (authority), which then have to be integrated to your frontend/backend solution and store that provided jwt in backend and only sending cookies in header? This is complicated I think, I dont know how to integrate google authentication so I am handing my own JWT (self-authorized) which you are saying is insecure... There is tradeoff between complexity and security then

Comment: If someone showed me a solution with that (using google and then using BBF pattern, RT token and ID token as you suggest), I would readily use that solution. But I cannot come up with that thing myself if I am berely learning spring security with JWT. And of course I am learning from tutorial (reading oauth2 spec does not shows full solution, neither does reading spring security docs), and of course THEY, in tutorial are using self-authorized jwt (insecure), because its easier to implement

Comment: no its not a tradeoff, thats why you use a security framework like spring security. To avoid the complexity, thats why spring has built a oauth2 rfc compliant client for you to use to avoid all the complexity. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/core.html why include a security framework if you dont inted to aactually learn it and use its features?

Comment: Also, forcing real users to use google account (because thats what google authentication requires), could be inconvenient for the users instead of the plain email/password. And google authentication service would then become and integral part of your application because you would not run it without that service (so big dependency). If prerequisite for using oauth2 is to be dependent on big companies to authenticate (google, microsoft, etc), then its not general and creates dependence

Comment: _neither does reading spring security docs_ well if the docs dont help you, then ask about the docs. I and everyone here would gladly explain the meaning of the docs if you extract a piece of it and ask about it and what you dont understand. The spring guys are here often and how can they improve the docs if no one asks about them, so they know what to improve in the docs?

Comment: @Toerktumlare give a real life **full** (working app) example?

Comment: So your reasoning is that you would rather build an insecure application that is vulnerable to several exploits, than to create a google account? or host your own issuer (spring authorization server) or just use a cookie (Spring Security FormLogin). If security isnt your actual priority, then you can just skip security all together. And i wish you good luck.

Comment: @Toerktumlare its not about me, but users. Users pay for your app. And what if they dont have google account? Will you force them? They could leave for that (I would personally, should I have google account for using application, even though I have google account, but not because someone forced me to have one)

Comment: if users pay for your app, i think they expect proper security. But im talking to a brick wall here apparently. Its apparent that good security is not your priority, i hope your users will accept that too. Good luck

Comment: ... or in other words. email/password authentication is deprecated and lets just make monopoly google know every users personal data for convenience... That's what you are trying to tell me? How many services on internet actually does use google as primary mean of authentication? Majority? I dont think so. I think majority are still relying on the "insecure" email/password authentication...

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about, google, facebook, all sites in the world rely on email/password with added 2 factor. What i am disccussing with you is what gets handed out AFTER the authentication has been performed. And how that is stored and can be exploited. Im done here, as pointed out its clear that you have no interest in good security, no interest in learning or make an effort learning. I have no obligation to force you either. So once again good luck.

Comment: ...another aspect: becuase you ARE using third party service (google) you WILL pay for it (https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/pricing). So not only you are giving away your users authentication data. You also paying for it... only so that you can declare "my app is properly secured" (as if creating your own identity service could no be possible and could not be secure as well)

Answer (score -1):

For creating REST APIs in Spring Boot 3 with Spring Security. This is the best way you can enable CORS(cross origin resource sharing).

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration) throws Exception {
        // Other Stuff
        http.cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(request -> corsConfiguration));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        return corsConfiguration;
    }

}
```

This question is already answered at many places.

Comment: Thid is not the best way. Opening you REST API for everyone is a big security risk. However, your solution wouldn't work, because OP's client code is using  `withCredentials: true` 
 and you can't use it with wildcards (`*`) together.

Comment: @dur by saying this is the best way doesnt means the person exactly needs to follow the configs as shown. It is just to give idea and show the right way. In many places ppl are suggesting mvc configure  ... why there always some random dude comes on someone's answer and down rate it without no reason? everyone here likes to criticize and show off there two weeks of experience from youtube

Answer (score -1):

I have solved that by using `allowCredentials = "true"` on the controller:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:3000"}, allowCredentials = "true")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuthController {
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private UserService userService;
    private JwtService jwtService;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<RegisterDtoout> register(@RequestBody RegisterDtoin registerDtoin) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.createUser(registerDtoin));
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody LoginDto loginDto) {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                 new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                         loginDto.getUsername(),
                         loginDto.getPassword()
                 )
        );
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String token = jwtService.createToken(authentication.getName());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(token);
    }
}
```

Now there is a warning that allowing credentials handling is

> > warning: allowing credentials opens high surface of attack and should be established only between trusted parties

which client service and server ARE, trusted parties as they are part of one app, and I dont know any other way to handle JWT token, besides via browser (like how else? Via email?), as someone mentioned in the comments.

Also I see this solution to be more granular, as specifying origins directly per controller, as authentication is in one controller and others dont need CORS as in other controllers are no jwt generating