# CORS problems with Spring-security

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, spring-boot

I am building an app with Spring-boot (on http://localhost:8080) and angular (on http://localhost:80).

the frontend and backend code are served by 2 different servers. In order to avoid CORS problems, I used to put in place an intermediate nginx server but I am not satisfied with this solution anymore. Hence, I have to allow CORS.

I allowed CORS globally with those lines :

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {   

  @Override
  public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost")
        .allowCredentials(true)
    ;
  }
}
```

This **works** for every routes **except for the authentication route** which is handled with Spring security :

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .formLogin()
      .successHandler(successHandler())
      .failureHandler(failureHandler())
    //[...]
  }

  private AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
    return (httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, authentication) ->
      httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
  }

  private AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler() {
    return (httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, e) -> {
       httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    };
}
```

Here is the code that sends the request on the frontend part :

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/login', $.param({'username': username, 'password': password}),
            {headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}
).then(function() {})
.catch(function(error) {};
```

If I enter the correct password, the http response code (that I can see in the Chrome console) is `200` but I still reach the `catch` block (with error.status = -1) and I can see this error message in the console :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/api/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

If I enter the wrong password I also reach the catch block with this error message :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/api/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

I also notice that CORS response headers are missing when I call the authentication endpoint.

Any ideas?

EDIT : it works if I manually add headers in the custom success handler. I would prefer if Spring-security could take into account the global CORS configuration.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035055/spring-boot-and-cors/35040051#35040051 probably this can save your time :)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience you'll need to include the port number in CORS, the error message from the browser is a bit misleading.

You can verify that by inspecting network and check the `Origin` field of your request headers. The value in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` of your response headers must match that exactly including protocol and port.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look on Spring website. There are solutions for consuming web service and managing CORS :

- **Enabling Cross Origin Requests for a RESTful Web Service :** https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/
- **Consuming a RESTful Web Service with AngularJS :** https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue two thing you could do,

1. `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")` add this to the service methods. The idea behind this is you enable CORS request through your service itself.
2. Use JSONP, but this has certain limitation. Also i wasnt successful in implementing it, so i used the above option.