# Spring Boot and OAuth2 CORS

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors

when we access the apis from a node server using axios client it always run in to the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8089/public/api. Redirect from 'http://localhost:8089/public/api/' to 'http://localhost:8089/' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3002' is therefore not allowed access.
```

My configuration as follows:

```
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.Filter;

import org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.UserInfoTokenServices;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.NestedConfigurationProperty;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientContext;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableOAuth2Client;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsUtils;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Client
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Order(6)
public class MonitoringApiApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
                .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","/user**", "/login**", "/webjars/**").permitAll().anyRequest()

                .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/")).and().logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().and().csrf().disable()
                .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http.antMatcher("/me").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
            // @formatter:on
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(MonitoringApiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(filter);
        registration.setOrder(-100);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("github")
    public ClientResources github() {
        return new ClientResources();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("facebook")
    public ClientResources facebook() {
        return new ClientResources();
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter() {
        CompositeFilter filter = new CompositeFilter();
        List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
        filters.add(ssoFilter(facebook(), "/login/facebook"));
        filters.add(ssoFilter(github(), "/login/github"));
        filter.setFilters(filters);
        return filter;
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter(ClientResources client, String path) {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
                path);
        OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);
        oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.setRestTemplate(oAuth2RestTemplate);
        UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(),
                client.getClient().getClientId());
        tokenServices.setRestTemplate(oAuth2RestTemplate);
        oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
        return oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter;
    }

}

class ClientResources {

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails client = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private ResourceServerProperties resource = new ResourceServerProperties();

    public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public ResourceServerProperties getResource() {
        return resource;
    }
}
```

Filter configuration:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean  corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3002");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(0);
    return bean;
}
```

spring boot version:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

if i add /public/** to antMatchers it works ,which means the enpoints are not protected by the ssoFilter() , i have tried credentials to false origin to *  but none of the worked

Comment: May be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035055/spring-boot-and-cors?rq=1 is of some help to you

Answer (score 15):

You need to add this http.cors().and().csrf().disable(); and also the filter inside the SecurityConfig file.

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins("*");
    configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

You need one of the latest version of spring security for this to work.

Comment: After doing all the documentation, stackoverflow, google examples, this is the only think that enabled CORS for me.

Answer (score 3):

For me , the only solution that worked was from this link:

[Spring security, cors error when enable Oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44625488/spring-security-cors-error-when-enable-oauth2)

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@WebFilter("/*") //TODO Exclude API endpoints when possible
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    public CorsFilter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fc) {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("doFilter");
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response
                .setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, origin, x-requested-with, authorization, " +
                        "Content-Type, Authorization, credential, X-XSRF-TOKEN");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

I also needed to remove http.cors() from configure methods from the classes that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter.