# Using CORS endpoints in application.properties instead of @CrossOrigin

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, cors, spring-boot-actuator

I am using Spring boot with gradle build and have added the below properties in application.properties.

```
endpoints.cors.allowed-origins=* 
endpoints.cors.allowed-methods=*
```

But when I do AJAX call from another domain, it is giving error as below:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:9000/hello-world. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Firefox:
Host
localhost:9000
Origin
localhost:9002
Referer 
localhost:9002/hello

build.gradle has the dependencies as:

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
```

Controller:9000

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello-world")
public class HelloWorldController {
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
     public @ResponseBody Greeting sayHello(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false) String name) {
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
}

}
```

AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("hii")
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:9000/hello-world"
    }).then(function(data, status, jqxhr) {
       $('.greeting-id').append(data.id);
       $('.greeting-content').append(data.content);
       console.log(jqxhr);
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot and CORS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035055/spring-boot-and-cors)

Comment: This is not a duplicate as I am not using any annotations or any filter class for CORS implementation. I am purely trying with the properties file configuration(actuator concept) i.e. endpoints.cors.allowed-origins rather than the class.

Comment: I think this config in the app properties is only there for Springs own actuator, not your custom code

Comment: But according to the Spring boot doc, the cors endpoints implementation came from 1.3.0 version onwards. I am new to this so not aware of this much.