# GET http://localhost:4200/resource 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular-httpclient

I am trying to get data from a Spring boot application to an Angular application.

My Angular component has the following code:

```ts
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    http.get('resource').subscribe(data => this.greeting = data);
}
```

My Spring boot controller has the following code:

```java
@RequestMapping("/resource")
public Map<String,Object> home() {
    Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    model.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    model.put("content", "Hello World");
    return model;
}
```

However, when I run this application, I get a 404 error as seen in the image below:

[image]

Comment: check where your spring boot app is running, usually port 8080

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should request the domain that your server is bootstrapped on. 
In this case, you are making a GET request to `localhost:4200` which is the default Angular CLI domain+port.

So you are making a request to the same port your Front-end application is on.

If you server is up on `localhost:3000` you would do the get request like so:

```
`this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/resources`).subscribe()...`
```

Comment: I have changed the code and getting new error. I think it is because i'm using spring-boot security. see updated post. How to solve this one?

Comment: @LahiruGamage I rolled back your changes. You can't change the intent of your question, because that would make this answer invalid. If you encounter a new problem, you should ask a new question. However, since it's a CORS issue, you should probably just look around for solutions first. CORS issues have been answered multiple times on Stack Overflow so far, for example [Spring Boot and CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035055/spring-boot-and-cors).

Comment: The example you have provided will not solve my problem. I think that problem is now with angular http call. @g00glen00b

Comment: @LahiruGamage You can open another issue and we can help there. But I assume I helped you fix this issue, so you can close this question.

Comment: I will. thnak you both