# CORS error when post request is send, but not get request in Spring Boot and Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cors

I am learning spring boot and react right now.

And I run into a problem of CROS. After spending some time researching about this issue, what i understand is that when malicious access tries to get information stored in cache, it would prevent the access. Now, my web application consider my api request as malicious access.

So I added @CrossOrigin annotation in BookResourceImp.java. In the tutorial I watch, after adding @CrossOrign in the file, everything works fine.

However, when i send post request to application, i get a CROS error. although my get request works fine.

Some solution introduce response.setHeader in java file as here
[Spring Boot and CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035055/spring-boot-and-cors)
but since the guy in the tutorial was adding only CrossOrigin annotation, I would like to know why mine does not work although get request works.
and if the solution from above link is the best option, please let me know.

Thank you so much in advance.

Book.js

```
import React from 'react';

import {Card, Form, Button, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';

import {FontAwesomeIcon} from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {faSave, faPlusSquare} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

import axios from 'axios';

export default class Book extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = this.initialState;
    }

    initialState = {
        title: '',
        author: '',
        url: '',
        isbn: '',
        price: '',
        lang: '',
    }

    submitBook = e => {
        alert(`${this.state.title}\n ${this.state.author}\n ${this.state.url}\n ${this.state.isbn}\n ${this.state.price}\n ${this.state.lang}\n ${this.state.title}`);
        e.preventDefault();

        const book = {
            title: this.state.title,
            author: this.state.author,
            url: this.state.url,
            isbn: this.state.isbn,
            price: this.state.price,
            lang: this.state.lang
        }

        axios.post("http://localhost:8081/rest/books", book)
            .then(res => {
                console.log("RES", res);
                if (res.data != null) {
                    this.setState(this.initialState);
                    alert("Book saved successfully")
                }
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    bookChange = e => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    }


    render() {

        const {title, author, url, isbn, price, lang} = this.state;

        return (
            <Card className={"border border-dark bg-dark text-white"}>
                <Card.Header><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSave} className="mr-2"/>Add Book</Card.Header>

                <Form id="bookFromId" onSubmit={this.submitBook}>
                    <Card.Body>
                        <Form.Row>
                            <Form.Group controlId="FormGridTitle" as={Col}>
                                <Form.Label>Title</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="title"
                                    value={title}
                                    placeholder="Book Titile"
                                    className={"bg-dark text-white"}
                                    name='title'
                                    required
                                    onChange={this.bookChange}
                                />
                            </Form.Group>

                            <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail" as={Col}>
                                <Form.Label>Author</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="text"
                                    value={author}
                                    placeholder="Author"
                                    className={"bg-dark text-white"}
                                    name='author'
                                    onChange={this.bookChange}
                                    required
                                />
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Form.Row>

                        <Form.Row>
                            <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail" as={Col}>
                                <Form.Label>Cover Photo URL</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="text"
                                    value={url}
                                    placeholder="Book Titile"
                                    className={"bg-dark text-white"}
                                    name='url'
                                    onChange={this.bookChange}
                                    required
                                />
                            </Form.Group>

                            <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail" as={Col}>
                                <Form.Label>ISBN Number</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="text"
                                    value={isbn}
                                    placeholder="Author"
                                    className={"bg-dark text-white"}
                                    name='isbn'
                                    onChange={this.bookChange}
                                    required
                                />
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Form.Row>

                        <Form.Row>
                            <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail" as={Col}>
                                <Form.Label>Price</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="text"
                                    value={price}
                                    placeholder="Book Titile"
                                    className={"bg-dark text-white"}
                                    name='price'
                                    onChange={this.bookChange}
                                    required
                                />
                            </Form.Group>

                            <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail" as={Col}>
                                <Form.Label>Language</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="text"
                                    value={lang}
                                    placeholder="Author"
                                    className={"bg-dark text-white"}
                                    name='lang'
                                    onChange={this.bookChange}
                                    required
                                />
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Form.Row>

                    </Card.Body>
                    <Card.Footer style={{"textAlign": "right"}}>
                        <Button size="sm" variant="success" type="submit">
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlusSquare} className="mr-2"/>Submit
                        </Button>
                    </Card.Footer>
                </Form>
            </Card>
        );
    }
};
```

BookResourceImp.java

```
package com.mightyjava.resource.impl;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


import com.mightyjava.domain.Book;
import com.mightyjava.exception.ApplicationException;
import com.mightyjava.exception.BookNotFoundException;
import com.mightyjava.resource.Resource;
import com.mightyjava.service.IService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/books")
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:3000")
public class BookResourceImpl implements Resource<Book> {
    
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BookResourceImpl.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private IService<Book> bookService;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Book>> findAll() {
        log.info("BookResourceImpl - findAll");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your @RequestMapping("/books") appears to only allow /books whereas your post request is to: "http://localhost:8081/rest/books".

Adding this webconfigurer will enable cors for the whole application:

```
package com.codurance.marsroverapi.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

  @Configuration
  public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
      registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help. I have a question. where can i add this code? Am I supposed to add it in the RestController or create a file and add this code in? what i found online seems to be the first option, add the code in RestController....

Comment: I usually add this in a config folder. It is added through injection to the application.

Comment: Yes, add this class on the folder where you keep your application-level configuration like MVC, Security, DB config.

Answer (score 0):

**Add this on your class path** everything will be ok

```
    @Component
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public class MyCorsFilterConfig implements Filter {

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Type, enctype");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            if (HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name().equalsIgnoreCase(((HttpServletRequest) req).getMethod())) {
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {
        }

        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        }


    }
```

Comment: Hi I appreciate for your help. Question, when you say class path, do you mean a RestController? or Create a new file and add this code in?

Comment: Create a new file and add this class on the folder where you keep your application-level configuration like MVC, Security, DB config